# Issue running a .SH file on server reboot - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, nginx

I am having an issue getting the .sh file to run. I can run it via sudo ./starter.sh when inside my app directory, but relying for it on reboot isn't working.

I am using an Ubuntu 12.04 VM on Windows 7. I have my files on Windows shared with the VM, so I access my files via /mnt/hgfs/nodejs-test

I am running a node.js server with Nginx via my local VM.

As of right now, I can go to http://node.dev and it will properly load up my server.js located in nodejs-test (/mnt/hgfs/nodejs-test) and output hello world to the screen.

So running the site isn't a problem..but getting forever (forever.js installed globally) to kick in on reboot isn't working. **I suspect it simply can't execute my SH file.**

Here is my **starter.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ $(ps aux | grep $USER | grep node | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -s "\n") -eq 0 ]

  then

  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

  forever start --sourceDir /mnt/hgfs/nodejs-test/server.js >> /mnt/hgfs/nodejs-test/serverlog.txt 2>&1

fi
```

Now I have tried sudo crontab -e (and added my path to the file) as well as just crontab -e and did the same thing. Upon reboot...nothing.

```
@reboot /mnt/hgfs/nodejs-test/starter.sh
```

I tried editing that cronjob to this

```
@reboot /var/www/nodejs-test/starter.sh
```

because I created a symlink in /var/www/nodejs-test to /mnt/hgfs/nodejs-test

Where can I check to see if an error fires on reboot, or is it possible my reboot cron isn't running at all? I know running the starter.sh DOES work though.

**EDIT** The /mnt/hgfs/nodejs-test is owned by root (which might be a windows thing given the files exist on my Windows 7 os). My ubuntu user is "bkohlmeier" which I created on installing the VM.

**EDIT #2**

```
Nov 10 13:05:01 ubuntu cron[799]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Nov 10 13:05:01 ubuntu cron[875]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Nov 10 13:05:01 ubuntu cron[875]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Nov 10 13:05:02 ubuntu CRON[887]: (bkohlmeier) CMD (/mnt/hgfs/nodejs-test/starter.sh)
Nov 10 13:05:02 ubuntu CRON[888]: (root) CMD (/var/www/nodejs-test/starter.sh >/dev/null2>&1)
Nov 10 13:05:02 ubuntu CRON[877]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Nov 10 13:05:02 ubuntu CRON[878]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: I don't know, but seems from the cron log that it does see the sh and tries to execute it right ?

Comment: Yea, that is what it seems..and even seems like it tries via my username and root. But even if I do a simple  mkdir blah inside the SH file, that never fires.

Comment: I tried another, called it test.sh, and it's only job is to mkdir test1. When I run it via  ./test.sh it works great..when I set it in the crontab and reboot, nada. grrrrrr

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. Whether it is the "right" solution I don't know. Because my system shares files between HOST and GUEST (windows 7 and Ubuntu VM), the /mnt/hgfs/ has to get mounted (I think)..and the reboot happens quick enough I think the mount isn't aware yet.

So I added this via crontab -e

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 15; /var/www/nodejs-test/starter.sh
```

and it worked like a charm.

Comment: does it work if you move the `sleep` inside the `sh` file in the beginning ?